# How do I create a temporary table for a dynamic query so that I can BCP the output

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, bcp

I am trying to write a stored procedure that executes all `.sql` files that are in a folder, and then outputs the results to CSV files.

My code:

```
DECLARE @Table table(
    [FileName] varchar(100),
    depth int,
    isFile int
)

DECLARE @Result int
DECLARE @FileName VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @exportFile VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @ExportPath VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @SQLText VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @FilePath VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @FULLPATH VARCHAR(200)
DECLARE @BULKEXEC NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Cmd nvarchar(1000)

SET @FilePath = 'c:\temp'
SET @ExportPath = 'c:\temp\output'

INSERT INTO @Table
EXEC master..xp_dirtree @FilePath,1,1

DELETE FROM @Table WHERE isFile=0

DECLARE FileList CURSOR STATIC FOR SELECT [FileName] FROM @Table WHERE FileName LIKE '%.sql'
OPEN FileList
FETCH FIRST FROM FileList INTO @FileName
    WHILE @@Fetch_Status = 0
        BEGIN
            SET @exportFile = REPLACE(@FileName,'.sql','.csv')
            SET @FULLPATH = @FilePath + '\' + @FileName
            SET @BULKEXEC = 'SELECT @SQLText = BulkColumn FROM OPENROWSET(BULK ''' + @FULLPATH + ''', SINGLE_BLOB) as x'  

            EXEC sp_ExecuteSQL @BULKEXEC, N'@SQLText VARCHAR(MAX) output ', @SQLText output

            EXEC (@SQLText)



            SET @Cmd = 'bcp "SELECT * FROM ##Temptable" queryout "' + @ExportPath + '\' + @exportFile + '" -c -t, -T'

            EXEC @Result = master..xp_cmdshell @cmd

            FETCH NEXT FROM FileList INTO @FileName
        END
CLOSE FileList
DEALLOCATE FileList
```

This currently executes the files, but I'm missing the middle bit that uploads the results to the `##Temptable`.

Is anyone able to help?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by _"I'm missing the middle bit"_?

Comment: @TT. So far I have the code to run the queries, and some code to export data to a csv. I cannot work out the code to populate the ##Temptable, with the varying results from executing the SQLText, to enable me to export the results of the queries. Or if there is a more suitable method of exporting the results to a csv file, what this might be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the following example. It uses a query in `@sqltext`, a quite generic query that selects information from the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` schema (`tables` and `columns`).

This query is then modified to insert the results into a global temporary table `##tt`, by looking for the first `FROM` keyword and inserting `INTO ##tt` at the proper location. The modified query is executed to insert the results of the query in the temporary table.

Finally the results are written to a text file using the `xp_cmdshell` procedure with a `BCP` command.

---

```
DECLARE @i INT=1;
WHILE @i<10
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sqltext NVARCHAR(MAX);
    IF @i%2=1 
        SET @sqltext='SELECT*FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables';
    ELSE
        SET @sqltext='SELECT*FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns';

    DECLARE @ii INT; SET @ii=CHARINDEX('FROM',@sqltext);

    SET @sqltext=LEFT(@sqltext,@ii-1)+' INTO ##tt '+SUBSTRING(@sqltext,@ii,LEN(@sqltext));
    EXEC(@sqltext);

    DECLARE @bcp_cmd NVARCHAR(4000);
    SET @bcp_cmd='BCP "SELECT*FROM ##tt" QUERYOUT "c:\temp\tt'+CAST(@i AS NVARCHAR)+'.txt" -c -t, -T -d ' + DB_NAME() + ' -S '+ @@SERVERNAME;
    EXEC xp_cmdshell @bcp_cmd;

    DROP TABLE ##tt;
    SET @i=@i+1;
END
```

---

If it is not possible to format the queries in the `.sql` files because they are complex scripts, the [sqlcmd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility) utility will be a lot easier to use. You can specify an input file (your SQL script) with `-i` and an output file (the CSV files) with `-o`. `-s` for the columns separator and so on.

Comment: Thanks for your speedy response. I had already considered inserting the INTO command in the queries, this would have been a great solution as the ##Temptable would be created by the query itself. Unfortunately this solution is not suitable in this instance as some of the queries are quite complex and sometimes have temporary tables and/or sub-queries, and therefore have a FROM before the main FROM.

Comment: @Leigh Added alternative to BCP in the answer.

Comment: The sqlcmd pointer was just the help I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: I tried upvoting several times but it wouldn't allow me as I didn't have a high enough reputation. My reputation has just reached the level required and I have now upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else is looking to do similar my working code is as follows:

```
    DECLARE @Table table(
        [FileName] varchar(100),
        depth int,
        isFile int
    )

    DECLARE @Result int
    DECLARE @FilePath VARCHAR(100)
    DECLARE @FileName VARCHAR(100)
    DECLARE @Fullpath VARCHAR(200)
    DECLARE @exportFile VARCHAR(100)
    DECLARE @ExportPath VARCHAR(100)
    DECLARE @FullExportPath AS VARCHAR(200)
    DECLARE @Cmd nvarchar(1000)


    SET @FilePath = '\\192.168.7.111\c$\temp'
    SET @ExportPath = '\\192.168.7.111\c$\temp\output'

    INSERT INTO @Table
    EXEC master..xp_dirtree @FilePath,1,1

    DELETE FROM @Table WHERE isFile=0

    DECLARE FileList CURSOR STATIC FOR SELECT [FileName] FROM @Table WHERE FileName LIKE '%.sql'
    OPEN FileList
    FETCH FIRST FROM FileList INTO @FileName
        WHILE @@Fetch_Status = 0
            BEGIN
                SET @exportFile = REPLACE(@FileName,'.sql','.csv')
                SET @FullExportPath = @ExportPath + '\' + @exportFile
                SET @Fullpath = @FilePath + '\' + @FileName
                SET @cmd = 'sqlcmd -i "' + @Fullpath + '" -o "' + @FullExportPath + '" -h-1 -s"," -W'

                EXEC @Result = master..xp_cmdshell @cmd

                FETCH NEXT FROM FileList INTO @FileName
            END
    CLOSE FileList
    DEALLOCATE FileList
```